# InstallShield setup c#

Tags: c#, installshield

We frequently need to create setup of the different version of our platform code as they are released. Right now we create it manually.
The task is really simple. There is one folder which always contains the files which needs to be packaged. What I need is a way to create setup using a C# application.

Comment: Ever considered using something more professional? Every time I had to use InstallShield I literally got sick. WIX (wix toolset) is from Microsoft, and fully itnegrates with the build stack (xml based, msbuild project file etc- you can run it from the command line).

Answer (score 0):

simplest soultion is to use:
`New Project->Other Project Types->Setup AndDeployment VisualStudio Installer -> Setup Wizard`

just follow the instructions

its simple as using any toolbox item.

edit the project properties in the properties window

right click the project and use add/view menues for all other options

see:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, “Visual Studio Installer” projects are no longer supported in Visual Studio 2012.